Projection Operators and Tensor Product
I need some hints or ideas that I could use to solve this question:
Q) Let $A, B$ Idempotent, Hermitian, Linear Operators.
a) Firstly, show that: $\prod_A^a = \frac { (-1)^aA+1_V }{2}  $ is a project operating that projects onto the $(-1)^a$ eigenspace of A. Note that $V$ is a vector space and our given operators $A,B$ are in $\mathcal{L} (V)$ such that $A,B \colon V \to V$
In particular, I struggle to understand how one shows the latter half of the statement since I do not precisely understand what $(-1)^a$ eigenspace of A means.
b) Continuing with the question, secondly, express $\prod _{A \otimes B}^a$ in terms of $ \prod_A^a$ and $\prod_B^b$, and $a,b \in \{0,1\}$ .
Here I am not even sure what this looks like, I do not understand how to use $\prod _{A \otimes B}^a$ or even denote it.
Any and all help is appreciated, and I would appreciate it more if someone could explain this without having to give the exact end result.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
